# Splunk query to extract string inside XML tag not working with spath command

Tags: xml, splunk

I am using the following query:

```
index=itx "PAD =" | dedup BOC | spath output=Channel path=AsRunMessage.Header.Channel  | table BOC, channel
```

which results in events with big xml content .. I need to extract the string "ITX1546" from inside the  tags.
Also I need to create a table with distinct rows containing unique BOC values.
The Channel field is not being populated.
Here is the XML structure:

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate XML so I don't use `spath` enough to respond to that.  However, you may get away with using `rex` (although regular expressions are not the best way to parse XML).  This untested query should get you started.

```
index=itx "PAD =" | rex "<BOC [^>]+>(?<BOC>[^<]+)[\s\S]+<Channel [^>]+>(?<Channel>[^<]+)" 
| stats values(Channel) by BOC
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I had the BOC field so I just needed the Channel:
index=itx "PAD =" | dedup BOC | rex "<Channel [^>]+(?<Channel>[^<]+)" | table BOC, Channel | sort - BOC

The only problem is that I am pulling an extra character ">" as ">ITX2345"

Comment: I left out a `>` in one of the regex strings.  Sorry about that.  Answer has been revised.